# OSB - Is there a way to generate default errors for internal errors?

Tags: error-handling, osb

I have a validate action in the OSB request pipeline which raises an error if the request is not according the schema.

In the error handler, I remove the header info and add some required header info before replying with a failure. However the response I get is the request body and not the fault which is in $fault. Is there a way to have OSB generate a standard soapFault using the $fault variable instead of having to manually create the error response body?

I'm having the same issue with the general error handler defined for the business service and the pipeline error handler when internal errors are raised.

Additionally, Is there a best-practice on how this is usually done for normal services and in case of passthrough services?

thanks

Comment: In OSB you can have errors in 3 different place. In the $body, in the $fault and a soap fault from an external source. We created an xQuery that, depending on the OSB error and some other variables, takes the right error and maps it into a soapfault how we like it.

Comment: I also have an IF in my error handler which checks for specific errors but i'm kind of confused about the fact you have to manually create the response format.
I assume you also have your own error format and add it to the WSDL before sending it to the consumer? What if you are implementing pass-through services?

Comment: We have services where we made our own error format. You add this as a 'message' type in your WSDL and can specify this as a 'fault' per 'operation'. We also have services where we just map an error to a soap fault format with the information we would like to show our consumers.